# How to navigate between screens onPress button in React Native Navigation 5.0.9 (New)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am doing doing navigation with new react native all I want is when button is pressed it navigate to next screen, I have followed new documentation but the problem is I am doing with different classes and in the documentation the work is done with functions in App.js, I tried to modify my code accordingly but couldn't do with classes:
This is my class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight,Image,BackHandler} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Login from './Login';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function NavRules() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator >
        <Stack.Screen  component={Login} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default class Home extends Component {
  render({navigation}) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

What I want now is when it clicks on Login button it moves to next screen but it gives me error, like can't find variable navigation.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `navigation` is passed as `props` to your screen, not as a `render` method parameter.

Also, I don't see you `Home` component anywhere in your navigation configuration. Where is `NavRules()` called?

Try this instead:

```js
export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}>
                    <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it does. See the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating). It clearly says that the `navigation` object is passed as `props` to every screen.

Comment: I did that but it throws an error: "Undefined is not an object: evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate"

Comment: Plus NavRules() havent been called anywhere, I just make that function following the new navigation docs.

Comment: Then that's your problem, your `App.js` file should render what's inside you `NavRules` function. You also need to include your `Home` component as a `Stack.Screen`, otherwise the `navigation` prop will always be `undefined`.

Comment: My application flow is like first I created a splash screen which runs for two seconds then it goes to "Home" screen, I did that without navagation like calling the screen as component in ComponentdidMount(), app.js has nothing to do with it, thats why I made this NavRules() funcation in my Home screen

Comment: I posted complete code here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668530/undefined-is-not-an-object-navigation-navigate-react-native-navigation-5-new?noredirect=1#comment107338005_60668530)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass navigation props to your NavRules function. And You should give a name your stack screen which is you navigate to. I have edited your codes, you can check below.

```
function NavRules({navigation}) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator >
        <Stack.Screen name="Login"  component={Login} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    const {navigation} = this.props
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This do code does not work for me, as it gives error.

Comment: if you share full of your navigator and your screens, i can help more effective. i'm using navigation 5 and it works clearly.  i don't know where is your Home screen in your navigator. if it's in different navigator, you should navigate different way. if it isn't  in your navigator, you should define it in your NavRules navigator

Comment: Can u please share an example code of navigation 5 done with classes defining my problem?

Comment: I posted complete question over here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668530/undefined-is-not-an-object-navigation-navigate-react-native-navigation-5-new?noredirect=1#comment107338005_60668530)

Comment: i have created a react native init project and copied all of your code from the link. one different thing is i installed react navigation with myself. your code and navigation works clearly. I think you install react navigation again step by step  and most important thing is      >>>     "If you're on a Mac and developing for iOS, you need to install pods to complete the linking. Make sure you have Cocoapods installed. Then run:
Code:                             
                     cd ios; pod install